# What is the difference between the "protected" and "protected internal" modifiers in .NET?

Tags: .net, access-modifiers

What is the difference between the "protected" and "protected internal" modifiers in .NET?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Public, Private, Protected, and Nothing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614818/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-protected-and-nothing)

Answer (score 10):

**private**

> Access is only allowed from within a specific type

**protected**

> private access is expanded to include inheriting types

**internal**

> private access is expanded to include other types in the same assembly

And so it follows that:

**protected internal**

> private access is expanded to allow access for types that *either* inherit from or are in the same assembly as this type, or both.

Basically, think of everything as `private` first, and anything else you see as expanding on that.

Answer (score 7):

**`protected`**

> Members are only visible to inheriting types.

**`protected internal`**

> Members are only visible to inheriting types and also to all types that are also contained within the same assembly as the declaring type.

Here is a C# example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        // Notice I can call this method here because
        // the Foo type is within the same assembly
        // and the method is marked as "protected internal".
        foo.ProtectedInternalMethod();

        // The line below does not compile because
        // I cannot access a "protected" method.
        foo.ProtectedMethod();
    }
}

class Foo
{
    // This method is only visible to any type 
    // that inherits from "Foo"
    protected void ProtectedMethod() { }

    // This method is visible to any type that inherits
    // from "Foo" as well as all other types compiled in
    // this assembly (notably "Program" above).
    protected internal void ProtectedInternalMethod() { }
}
```

Comment: Indeed. It's protected OR internal, contrary to how it looks in the first place +1

Answer (score 2):

As usual, from one of [Fabulous Eric Lippert's blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/04/24/why-can-t-i-access-a-protected-member-from-a-derived-class-part-three.aspx):

> Many people believe that [`protected internal`] means *"M is accessible to all derived classes that are in this assembly."* It does not. **It actually means *"M is accessible to all derived classes and to all classes in this assembly"*.**  That is, it is the *less restrictive* combination, not the *more restrictive* combination.
>
> This is counterintuitive to a lot of people. I have been trying to figure out why, and I think I've got it. I think people conceive of `internal`, `protected`, and `private` as restrictions from the "natural" state of `public`. With that model, `protected internal` means "apply both the protected restriction and the internal restriction".
>
> That's the wrong way to think about it. Rather, `internal`, `protected` and `public` are weakenings of the "natural" state of `private`. `private` is the default in C#; if you want to make something have broader accessibility, you've got to say so. With that model, then it becomes clear that `protected internal` is a weaker restriction than either alone.

Answer (score 1):

for the difference between **`protected`** and **`protected internal`** lemme give a brief example and i will match the example ...

`Country A`: one assembly

`Country B`: another different assembly

`X`(Base Class) is dad of `Y`(Inherited Class) In Country A

`Z`(Inherited Class of `X`) is another son of `X` in Country B.

`X` has a property.

1. if `X` mentions the property as `protected` then
          `X` says: all my sons `Y` and `Z`, only you both can access my property wherever u stay...god bless you. No one can access my property except you.
2. if `X` mentions the property as `protected internal` then
          `X` says: All the people in my country `A` including my son `Y`, can access my property. dear son `Z`, still you can access my property in `Country B`.

hope you guys understood...

thank you.