# what does it mean "private xxxxxxx" in visual studio ArcObjects using c#?

Tags: c#, arcobjects

I am new to ArcObjects using c# in visual studio 10. In some code, it often have something like this:

```
private bool m_isMouseDown = false;
private ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.INewLineFeedback m_lineFeedback;
private IActiveView m_focusMap;
```

Can someone tell me what is the meaning? Does it mean in the code following these description, m_fucusMap will indicate or represent IActiveView?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you do any research before posting this question?

Comment: Look up C# Fields and C# Access Modifiers.

Comment: You should really start with a [C#/.NET tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh341490).

Answer (score 2):

`private` means that a method (function) or variable can only be accessed within the class in which you're declaring it.

Read this:
[What is the difference between Public, Private, Protected, and Nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614818/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-protected-and-nothing)

You might want to learn some more about C# or object-oriented programming in general if you're not familiar with these concepts.

Comment: To Corey Ogburn:sorry, do you mean if i am confused, I can't post a question.