# What is the difference between "private" and "protected Internal"?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, access-modifiers

I just want to know what is the actual difference between **private** and  **protected internal** access specifier. As i know

> ***Visible to own class members:*** private and protected internal **YES**
>
> ***Visible to object of other classes:*** Both **NO**
>
> ***Visible to objects of other classes outside the namespace collection:*** Both **NO**
>
> ***Visible to object of child classes outside the namespace collection:*** Both **NO**

If **private** doing the same as **protected internal** then why we need the both just one should be enough or not?

Comment: The Type.IsFamilyOrAssembly property will be true.  OR, not AND.

Comment: @HansPassant I did not get you? Sorry.

Comment: Good Resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Public, Private, Protected, and Nothing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614818/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-protected-and-nothing)

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/What-is-the-difference-between-public-private-protected-and-having-no-access

Answer (score 27, accepted):

- A `protected internal` member is visible to any code in the current assembly **or** in a derived class in another assembly. In technical words, it's the [**logical disjunction**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) of `protected` and `internal`.
- A `private` member is visible only to code in the same class.

`protected internal` is actually the second most permissive access modifier after `public`.

---

It's worth noting that `protected` is arguably *more* permissive than `internal`, since it allows access from code that you have no control over (i.e. other assemblies). While `internal` allows access from *all* code in the current assembly, this code is yours and you have control over it!

To paraphrase, `protected` (and `protected internal`) members are part of the public API of your assembly (and should therefore be documented). `internal` members are not.

Comment: So when should I determine to use `protected internal` instead of `public`?

Comment: @François Your last sentence isn't actually true; `protected internal` is the **union** of the two, not the intersection.

Answer (score 26):

A graphical overview (summary in a nutshell)

[image: Visibility]

Comment: There should be another column called Derived Classes in another assembly - for the protected internal keyword.

Comment: @Lyubomir Velchev: True, there should be two rubrices anyway (same assembly, different assembly), and in this graphic the internal "derived class" no-value should be hatched.

Answer (score 4):

`private` is *only* visible to own class members, whereas `protected internal` is visible to child classes *as well as* to other classes inside the namespace collection.

Comment: So `private` is visible to  `child classes as well as to other classes inside the namespace collection.`

Comment: @avirk No, that's `protected internal`. `private` is the strictest access modifier: only available to the defining class.

Answer (score 3):

**private**

> The type or member can only be accessed by code in the same class or
>   struct.

**protected internal**

> The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly,
>   or by any derived class in another assembly

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to understand the differences between protected internal and internal in .NET context by reading the description provided different forums and blogs. I really failed to understand then I created created 2 separate assembly using VS2015. Probably now I have basic understanding. I would like to share with you, it might be helpful to somebody. I tried to use the fields declared in one assembly from another assembly. Also I tried  derived from a class that was declared in another assembly. 
Here is the code for class1.cs from assembly 1

```
namespace Z_Dll_1
{
    public class PublicBaseClassAssemblyOne
    {
        internal int _myinternal = 200;
        protected internal int _protectedinternal = 100;
        protected int _myProtected = 123;
        private int _myPrivate = 2;
        public int _myPublic = 45;
    }

    public class DerivedClassAssemblyOne : PublicBaseClassAssemblyOne
    {
        protected internal int intM = 10;
    }

    internal class MyInternalClass
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method one with internal class");
            PublicBaseClassAssemblyOne cl1 = new PublicBaseClassAssemblyOne();
            cl1._myinternal = 1000; //Internal type is available since it is in same assembly
            cl1._protectedinternal = 10; // protected internal is available
            cl1._myPublic = 2;  // Public OK
            //cl1.myPrivate = ?? // nor available since it is private

            DerivedClassAssemblyOne drOne = new DerivedClassAssemblyOne();
            drOne._myinternal = 30; // Internal and available from derived class
            drOne._myPublic = 1; // Public 
            drOne._protectedinternal = 2; // Able to be accessed from same assembly or derived class from other assembly
        }
    }
}
```

Here is code from another assembly, class2.cs
    using Z_Dll_1;

```
namespace Z_Dll_2
{
    public class ClassAssembly2
    {
        public ClassAssembly2()
        {
            PublicBaseClassAssemblyOne classfromOtherAssembly = new PublicBaseClassAssemblyOne();
            classfromOtherAssembly._myPublic = 0; //Only public is available
        }
    }

    public class ClassDerivedFromOtherAssemblyClass : PublicBaseClassAssemblyOne
    {
        public ClassDerivedFromOtherAssemblyClass()
        {
        }
        void ClassDerivedFromOtherAssemblyClassTestMethod()
        {
            //_myinternal = 200; // can't access since it was internal to other assembly
            _protectedinternal = 100; // this can be accessed as it is  derived class from other class that has protected internal 
            _myProtected = 123; // Ordinary protected data accessed from derived class
            //_myPrivate = 2; //Private member can't be accessed from  derived class
            _myPublic = 45; // Public can be accessed anyway

            //Try to create an instance of internal class
            //MyInternalClass intClass = new MyInternalClass(); //Not accessible from this assembly
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that protected internal means that only classes that inherit and are in the same assembly can see that property. Those that derive the class and are from different assembly, cannot see it.

LE: read Mattias Buelens comment for this.

Comment: Actually, this is incorrect. `protected internal` means `protected` *union* `internal`, so both child classes and other classes in the same assembly can see it.

Comment: @Mattias Buelens...My english was a bit bad, but what I wanted to say is now written.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit puzzling at first but it makes sense when you see that it's the *union* of both modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking practically, I typically only use private for variables to ensure they can't be misused by other classes.

Protected internal, however, I will often use for methods that I don't want most other classes to be able to use, but that I want to be able to access to write test cases.  It is very handy in that it allows test classes to be created in the sane namespace or package structure that can then access those protected internal methods without inappropriately opening them up to the rest of the world.

This approach does require an approach to coding where writing easily "testable" code is a priority.  If this wasn't my approach, I'm not sure I would find many occasions to use protected internal.

Comment: The choice of access modifier should not be determined by your need for testing. If for example you have a property which does not require a setter you would not add a public setter simply to allow it to be set for testing. Test frameworks along with mocking frameworks are able to inject into private properties and so on. Testing influences your choice in patterns or possibly even abstraction, after all, it is hard to unit test something if you can't mock any dependencies. Testing should not impact your choice of access modifiers though.

Comment: +1 Francois, I also often see people making private members 'internal', together with the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` to expose them to a unit test assembly.