# Classes & pure virtual

Tags: c++, virtual

I have 4 classes.

`class A`, `class B`, `class C`, `class D`

Class `C` includes class `A` and class `B` and reference them:

The Header File:

```
class C
{
private:
    A &a;
    B &b;
    int x;
    int y;
    int energy;
public:

    C(A &a, B &b);

          void print(void);

    virtual void printAt(void);
```

CPP File includes:

```
void C::printAt(void)
{
    // move cursor to the current x, y coordinates
    b.gotoXY(x,y);
}
```

In class `D`, I make class `C` a friend class by (`class D : public class C...`)

Then I have a `void printAt(void)`.

This all works, but how do I access the b class attributes (`b.gotoXY..`) from class `D`?

Hopefully this makes Sence.

Comment: You don't make it _"friend"_, you inherit from it.

Comment: Go read up on [inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/860353/57318) and [public/protected/private access](http://stackoverflow.com/a/614844/57318). We can answer this for you, but I fear that you won't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Just put them in `protected` section:

```
class C {
protected:
  A &a;
  B &b;

  ...
};
```

**NOTE:** It has nothing to do with `virtual` methods.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot access them from `D` is because they are `private`, which means they are only accessible from within `D` itself. In order to be able to access them only from `D` or its subclasses, you need to use the `protected` access modifier instead:

```
class C
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    int energy;

protected:
    A &a;
    B &b;

public:
    C(A &a, B &b);

    void print(void);

    virtual void printAt(void);
    /// ...
};
```

Now, a bit of terminology:

When you type `class C : public D` you are not making it a `friend`, you are inheriting from it. This means `C` will be a base class of `D`. A friend is another, related concept.

A friend of some class is another class which has access to its `private` properties. So, if you instead had made `D` a `friend` of `C`, you would have had access to `a` and `b` without having to make them `protected`. This would be accomplished as such:

```
class C
{
    // Some code...
    friend D;
    //Lots of code ...
}
```

Please note that, for this to work, you need to declare `D` before `C`.

**Now, which of these options should you use?**

Ask yourself this question: is a `D` logically a more specific type of `C`? If so, it should use inheritance. If not, it may be better to make `D` have a member of type `C` and use the `friend` keyword. In either case, use `friend` sparingly, and only if there is necessarily a very tight relationship between the two classes (perhaps if `D` is a factory for type `C` and `C` has a private constructor.)

Answer (score 0):

You should make intended members `protected` or make their classes `friend` to your class.

In addition, I feel you will have a problem when you instantiating an object from `C` because of uninitialized references.

```
class C
{
private:
    A &a;
    B &b;

    // ...

public:
    C(A &a, B &b) : a(a), b(b)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

when you want other class in inherit access to your attributes .dont private them
so you can choose protected or public.
for more detail you can go http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/115-inheritance-and-access-specifiers/
for solve problem try below code

```
class C
{
protected://or public
    A &a;
    B &b;
    int x;
    int y;
    int energy;
public:
    C(A &a, B &b);
    void print(void);
    virtual void printAt(void);
```

and in `class D`

```
class D:public C
{
public:
    void printAt(void);
};
```