# Why am I getting an "...is inaccessible due to its protection level" compile error in this C# code?

Tags: c#

As you can see, everything is set as public, but compiler says:

> `Shooting.inventoryWeapon.inventoryWeapon(Shooting.weapon, int)` is inaccessible due to its protection level.

This code is in class Shooting.

```
public enum weapon{gun,shotgun};

public struct inventoryWeapon{
    weapon current;
    int shotAmmo;
    inventoryWeapon(weapon cur,int shAmmo){
        current=cur;
        shotAmmo=shAmmo;
    }
}

public inventoryWeapon[] Inventory;
int weaponIndex=0;

void Start(){
    Inventory=new inventoryWeapon[10];
    Inventory[weaponIndex]= new inventoryWeapon(weapon.shotgun,30);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Public, Private, Protected, and Nothing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614818/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-protected-and-nothing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `public` here:

```
public inventoryWeapon(weapon cur,int shAmmo){
    current=cur;
    shotAmmo=shAmmo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have defined your class as public

```
public struct inventoryWeapon{
```

If you want to expose your class members to outside world you have to define your class members as public(unless you use inheretence).

```
public inventoryWeapon(weapon cur,int shAmmo){
```