# c# syntax for combining multiple actions

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know this is a very basic question, and I am sure there are answers for it already on the forum.  I don't even know how to properly phrase it to search, so here goes.  I have button that has the OnClick property set to "InsertCard" and the corresponding code of:

```
protected void InsertCard (object source, EventArgs e) {
SqlDataSource1.Insert();
}
```

This works exactly as intended.  I also want to clear all the text boxes on the page after the button is clicked.  If I change the OnClick property to "ClearText" and have the corresponding code of:

```
protected void ClearText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClearControls();

}
private void ClearControls()
{
    foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in c.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly too.

My question is how do I combine both actions into one, so that when I click the button, I insert the data to the database AND then clear all fields?  I have tried many variations but always get some type of compiler error.

Also, is there some type of guide to assist me in using the right syntax for asking questions/searching for answers?

Comment: What did you try? What error did you get?

Comment: Call `ClearControls` from your `InsertCard` event handler?

Comment: What have you tried? Can't you just call `ClearControls()` after calling `SqlDataSource1.Insert()`?

Comment: Side-note: Your inner `foreach` seems to be redundant since the outer one already iterates over all controls of that page.

Answer (score 5):

Why can't you just call both functions in your button click response?

```
protected void InsertCard (object source, EventArgs e) {
    SqlDataSource1.Insert();
    ClearControls();
}

private void ClearControls()
{
    foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in c.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this what you are asking? If not you may need to be more specific.

Comment: Jeremy, yes I did copy and paste from other examples and the more I do so, the more I understand about C#.  Your answer worked, I just didn't know the proper syntax for combing actions, now thanks to you showing me I do.  Now protected and private make much more sense.  I assume I can just keep adding privates and calling them from the protected section?

Comment: @Dkone  See this for an explanation of public, private, protected: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614818/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-protected-and-nothing

Comment: That was very helpful, especially the table someone made up.  I think I understand it a little.  So if I put some given code, whether it be public/private/protected at the top of my web page, it can only be called from 'that' webpage, but if I put it in the code behind page, then any page that references that code behind page can use the code?

Answer (score 2):

If I have not miss read the question just call the other function   after you have inserted your records.

```
protected void InsertCard (object source, EventArgs e) {
   SqlDataSource1.Insert();
   ClearControls();
}

private void ClearControls()
{
    foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in c.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```