# How to get the registered user control to code behind in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webusercontrol

I have register a page using the code

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="side" Src="side.ascx" %>
```

And called this by using the code

```
<uc1:side ID="Side1" runat="server"></uc1:side>
```

And i tried to acces the  ID="Side1" in behind  by using

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Put user code to initialize the page here

    if (Session["UName"] != null || Session["UName"] != " ")
    {
        Side1.Visible = true;
    }
    else
        Side1.Visible = true;
    }
```

but gives the error

> The name 'Side1' does not exist in the current context    .

How will i resolve it by accessing the 'id' using  'protected System.Web.UI'.

Comment: Maybe a typo, but are you missing a bracket after your if condition?

Comment: Are you try `FindControl("Side1")` method? reference: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: In side.ascx page we have some paragraph

Comment: Edit your question, add the code of your ascx class definition.

Comment: I think `Side` is `protected`. You should make `Side` `internal` .

Comment: Is your control inside of some sort of templated control, such as a Repeater?

Comment: no, it is not inside a repeater

Comment: Does the solution compile anyways? Try a clean and rebuild, or just a rebuild. The error should go away. If it doesn't go away, but the solution still compiles, then it's just Visual Studio being wonky. You can ignore the error.

Comment: Is there a code-behind associated with the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the access modifier on your WebUserControl partial class definition (ie YourControl.ascx.cs file), it should be something like this:

```
public partial class SideControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    // your code...
}
```

You can find more information about access modifiers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614818/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-protected-and-nothing).

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: By using above i modified the code  like  this   ' protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl head;
            private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {

                if (Session["UName"] != null)
                {
                    head.Controls.Add(this.LoadControl("header.ascx"));
                }'