# Dynamically add .aspx page or Usercontrol inside another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls, dynamic-controls

I want to prepend an aspx page with another page at runtime. 
I know the better solution would be to use a usercontrol, But for that I would have to put all the elements of my aspx page in a user control & do that for several pages. 
Isnt there a way to load an aspx page inside another page like a user control?
Also I would want to make all the fields readonly of the appended page. Is there a way I can do this?

If usercontrol is the only way, then I have a query.
When I loaded my userControl in my PageLoad event, I cannot cast the control to my usercontrol name, & because of that I cannot set a property of my control. 
**I want to do this, but this gives error at compile time**:

```
MyControl myUserControl =(MyControl)Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/MessageControl.ascx");
```

Here `MyControl` is not available (It is not recognizable by the compiler) I tried `Ctrl+Dot` on MyControl, the compiler is not adding any reference to it also, It gives the following error

> The type or namespace name 'MyControl' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**When I do this, it works:**

```
 var ctrl = LoadControl("~/Controls/MessageControl.ascx");
                MyPlaceholder.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

But now ctrl is not casted which prevents me to set a property of my user control.

Also does it matter If I instantiate the control in Page_Init instead of Page_load? Because in Page_Init I am unable to make a DB call, probably the assemblies/db config hasnt loaded in Page_Init..

Comment: What error do you see at compile time? Add it to your question. Also, verify the definition of your control class, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31726429/1548894) other question.

Comment: I have added the error in my original question. The full name of my usercontrol class is : "UserControl_MyControl". I tried casting using this also but it was not recognized by the compiler. Currently I have registered it in my .aspx page, After regsitering it in .aspx I can use the control class in my code behind. If am going to add 20 controls dynamically do I have to register all 20 in my .aspx page. Is this the normal behavior?

Comment: Access modifier is also public in my case : public partial class UserControl_MyControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl

Comment: Yes, you have to `<%@ Register %>` every user control you are going to use. If you are going to use them on many aspx pages, you could register those at your web.config pages->controls section only once for entire site.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I thought that wasn't normal otherwise what is the purpose of dynamically adding controls. Anyway thanks for clarifying.