# How to access protected member in an inherited class

Tags: c#

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Access
{
    public class Job
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        protected string JobName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Class2.cs**

```
public class Full: Access.Job
{

}

Full ful = new Full();
```

Why I'm not able to access the `ful.JobName` member?

Comment: You can access JobName in your Full class but not through a a Full reference like ful

Comment: You can access this property only in the Full class, not outside of the class. When you add "protected string Job { get { return this.JobName; } }" in the Full class, you will be able to use it even outside of the Full class.

Comment: No i'm not Able to Acces JobName But Id I'm able to access

Comment: *"No i'm not Able to Acces JobName But Id I'm able to access"* **What?** Sorry, this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Sorry I'm Able to accessing Id

Comment: Md DastageerJob: What they meant is that you can use JobName INSIDE the Full class (that is between the { } after the declaration of the class) but, since JobName is protected, you cant access it outside those brackets, even when you instanciate the Full class, or even the Job Class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because You are trying to access protected method from outside the class. Only public methods are available. You can access the property/variably/method that is protected, only in the inherited class, but not from outer code:

```
public class Full: Access.Job
{
    public void mVoid()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.JobName);
    }

    protected void mProtVoid()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.JobName);
    }

    private void mPrivateVoid()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hey");
    }
}

Full myFull = new Full();
myFull.mVoid();  //will work
myFull.mProtVoid(); //Will not work
myFull.mPrivateVoid(); //Will not work
```

If You need to get to the protected property, there are 2 ways (3 actually, but Reflection is the dirty way and should be avoided):

**1. Make it public**

If it will be set to public, it will be stil inherit and You can directly access it:

```
Full nFull = new Full();
Console.Write(nFull.JobName);
```

**2. Make a "wrapper"/"facade"**

Create new property or method, that will just access the hidden property and return it in expected format.

```
public class Full: Access.Job
{
    public string WrappedJobName { get { return this.JobName; } }
    public string WrappedJobName => this.JobName; //C# 6.0 syntax
}

Full mFull = new Full();
Console.WriteLine(mFull.WrappedJobName);
```

Comment: its Fine But Protected is work only which inherit from that class.  Here when i create   Full myFull = new Full();     myFull.JobName --->Why its not working

Comment: @MdDastageerJob Tatranskymedved already answered why it does not work, read a little

Comment: Because You are creating new instance -> You are sitting next to the object and You are allowed to access it's public methods and properties. If You try to access protected/private methods, it won't allow You. Because they are protected/private. Definition of language. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614818/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-protected-and-nothing