# c# - My .dll File isn't showing Up

Tags: c#, dll

I have created a .cs files that contain the following:

```
namespace SetUp
{
    class Config
    {
        public static object SetConfig(int code, bool print)
        {
           //My Code
        }
    }
}
```

Compiled it and added the reference to my main project called 'CSharp Side', for example. Added it to my project and everything is great. But my question is how do I access 'SetConfig()'? Because it doesn't recognize 'SetUp' or 'Config' in my code.

Comment: Change `Config` to `public`

Comment: Add the keyword `public` to the class definition. I.e: `public class Config`

Comment: Beside what Ofir says you have to add a 'using' statement at top of module with the naespace Setup.

Comment: Make your class public so that it can be accessed from other classes in the same namespace or different namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply make your class as `public`.

```
namespace SetUp
{
  public class Config
  {
    public static object SetConfig(int code, bool print)
    {
      //My Code
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can reference code in a different assembly by fully qualifying:

```
SetUp.Config.SetConfig(1, true);
```

or include the namespace with a `using` directive:

```
using SetUp;

class SomeClass
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        Config.SetConfig(1, true);
    }
}
```

Also, both the class and the method in the referenced assembly need the `public` modifier. Otherwise they won't be visible outside the assembly where they are defined.

Comment: It says:
'Config' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: this has been covered in depth, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/614844/1132334) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)