# Why "illegal" declare variables in another class can be complied successfully?

Tags: c#

I created a c# test class like below, I intend to test what gonna happen if I created one variable twice in and out of scope. But to my surprise, it runs and outputs the value "inside".

This is an illegal way to multiple declare a same variable if I wrote this code snippet into Main() method, the compiler error would occur accordingly. But how come it can work in a separate class? Then how can we avoid making such mistakes?

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                
            Test tst = new Test();
            tst.ScopeAlert();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        string scope = "outside";
        public void ScopeAlert()        
        {
            string scope = "inside";

            Console.WriteLine(scope);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Inside the `Test` class you declared a field called scope. To access it in your `ScopeAlert` method, you would write `this.scope`. You have also declared the local `scope` variable. There is nothing "illegal" about this.

Comment: I wholeheartedly concur with my learned colleague @zaitsman

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, though you are correct that these are *scopes*, the better jargon to use in this specific situation is *declaration space*. There is a subtle difference. A declaration space is a region of code in which no two things may be declared to have the same name (except for overloaded methods). A *scope* is a region of text in which a particular name may be used without qualification. They are closely related but they are not the same thing.

The rules of C# are that *declaration spaces for classes and locals are different, and allow the same name to be declared in both*. However, *nested declaration spaces for locals do not permit locals in inner spaces to shadow locals in outer spaces*.

Your example is legal because the declaration spaces are not both local.

If we had local spaces:

```
void M()
{
  { int j = 1; }
  { int j = 2; }
}
```

That's legal because they do not overlap.  But

```
void M()
{
  { int j = 1;  { int j = 2; } }
}
```

Is illegal because the spaces do overlap.

Consult the C# specification for more details.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is perfectly fine in C# and is allowed. If you need to access

```
string scope = "outside";
```

then need to use `this.scope`. More info on accessibility levels of variables like `private`, `public`, `internal`, `protected`, `protected internal` is here:

[In C#, what is the difference between public, private, protected, and having no access modifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614818/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-protected-and-having-no)

Also, you have a method:

```
public void ScopeAlert()        {
    string scope = "inside";

    Console.WriteLine(scope);
}
```

The variable defined with value "inside" can be accessed anywhere within the method. However, the following won't work:

```
public void ScopeAlert()        {
    while(true) 
    {
        string scope = "inside";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(scope);  // will give an error as scope is limited to {}.
}
```