# I get an error in the Unity console. I like to know what is means and how to solve it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to get the player ship game object to move to the next scene if all enemies are killed and won the game. I get an error in the Unity console says:

> Assets\Scripts\GameController.cs(57,25): error CS0122: 'SceneLoader.LoadNextScene()' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Currently, I can only go to the next scene when I change the value in the of this line:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
```

to (2) in the scene Loader.cs I added code to the game controller this here: the public void WinGame() method any feedback to what this error s means and how I can fix it is appreciated. :)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float levelLoadDelay = 2f;
    private int currentSceneIndex = -1;

    private void Awake()
    {
        currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        if (currentSceneIndex == 0)
        {
             Invoke("LoadFirstScene", 2f);
        }

        private void LoadNextScene()
        {
            int currentSceneIndex =   SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
            int nextSceneIndex = currentSceneIndex + 1;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(nextSceneIndex);
        }

        public void LoadFirstScene()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
        }
    }


using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Playables;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoreText;
    public Text restartText;
    public Text gameOverText;

    [SerializeField] private Text outcome;
    [SerializeField] private PlayableDirector masterTimelinePlayableDirector;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject playerShip;

    private bool winGame = false;
    private bool gameOver = false;
    private int score;
    private int enemiesLeft = 0;
    private SceneLoader sceneLoader;

    public bool allEnemiesKilled;
    public float enemiesInScene = 10.0f;
    public float enemiesKilled;

    void Start()
    {
        sceneLoader = FindObjectOfType<SceneLoader>();
        enemiesLeft = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Enemy>().Length;
        restartText.text = "";
        gameOverText.text = "";
        outcome.text = "";
        score = 0;
        UpdateScore();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (gameOver)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
            {
                 sceneLoader.LoadFirstScene();
            }
        }

        if (PlayerHealth.cur_health <= 0)
        {
            GameOver();
        }
    }

    public void WinGame()
    {
        if (enemiesKilled < enemiesInScene)
        {
             allEnemiesKilled = true;
        }

        sceneLoader.LoadNextScene();
    }

    public void DecreaseEnemyCount()
    {
        enemiesLeft--;
    }

    public void AddScore(int newScoreValue)
    {
        score += newScoreValue;
        UpdateScore();
    }

    void UpdateScore()
    {
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
    }

   public void GameOver()
   {
        gameOver = true;
        gameOverText.text = "Game Over!";

        if (enemiesLeft > 0)
        {
             outcome.text = "You Lose";
        }
        else
        {
            outcome.text = "You Win";
        }

        restartText.text = "Press 'R' for Restart";

        masterTimelinePlayableDirector.Stop();
        playerShip.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change it to public.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C#, what is the difference between public, private, protected, and having no access modifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614818/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-protected-and-having-no)

Comment: I'm sure you would have a bunch of solutions typing `is inaccessible due to its protection level` in your favorite search engine

Comment: I didn't find my issue with typing this any guidance is much appreciated ..

Comment: You still didnt find the solution? Make your `LoadNextScene()` function public in `SceneLoader script`.

Comment: You can access `private` members **only** from the same class, and `protected` members from that class and its inheritors. Make it `public` to access from outside.

Comment: Thank you for the first comment it removed the error. still can't go to next scene I update code in-game controller and in scene loader please look over once again. Thank you

Comment: Don't fix your code in your question. You edited and vandalized your own question. now, the methods are inside the `Start()` method

Comment: Your LoadNextScene is only a function available in Start, outside that.. its toast.

Comment: @BugFinder I will look into it Thank you

Comment: @BugFinder No, this wasn't the case when OP asked the question. Check the edit history, he vandalized his own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current code structure, the problem is that you have method defined inside the start function.

### Modified script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] float levelLoadDelay = 2f;
private int currentSceneIndex = -1;
 public static SceneLoader instance;

private void Awake()
{
    currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
instance = this;
}

private void Start()
{
    if (currentSceneIndex == 0)
    {
         Invoke("LoadFirstScene", 2f);
    }
}

    public void LoadNextScene()
    {
        int currentSceneIndex =   SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
        int nextSceneIndex = currentSceneIndex + 1;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(nextSceneIndex);
    }

    public void LoadFirstScene()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
```

You can now call the LoadNextScene by using the code:

```
SceneLoader.instance.LoadNextScene();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Muhammad I updated the code but still can't go to the next scene.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error or what happens now?

Comment: @IDarkCoder Hi yes, I still not getting to the next scene but the errors are gone.