# How do I bind to a list of string I've created?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have created a list within this class called myVar...

```
class FailedIgnoredRetrieved
    {

        public static async Task FailedIgnoredRetrievedAndShow(ListView commentLabel)
        {

            void AllEventsComment(string comment)
            {
                if (commentLabel != null)
                {
                    commentLabel.ItemsSource += comment; //+ "\n";
                }
            }

            AllEventsComment("...");
            var api = new ApiClient();
            var retrieved = ApiToken.Load();
            if (retrieved == null)
            {
                AllEventsComment("Failed, not signed in");
                App.SwitchIcon(NotifyIcons.GreyIcon);
            }
            else
            {
                var result = await api.GetAllEventsAsync(retrieved.Token);
                if (result.IsSuccessful)
                {

                    List<string> myVar = new List<string>();

                    void AddToList(string v)
                    {
                        myVar.Add(v);
                    }

                    foreach (var eventsText in result.Events)
                        if (eventsText.EventStatus == 1)
                        {
                            AddToList($"Red {eventsText.CheckId}");
                        }

                        else if (eventsText.EventStatus == 0)
                        {
                            AddToList($"Orange {eventsText.CheckId}");
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }     
}
```

I now want to use myVar List in FailedIgnoredWindow.xaml.cs to bind to for a ListView in FailedIgnoredWindow.xaml I'm struggling to understand how to set it as the ListView.ItemSource = i.e. how do I access the list in the other class?

```
 public partial class FailedIgnoredWindow : Window
    {


        public FailedIgnoredWindow()
        { 
            InitializeComponent();

            FailedIgnoredDialogue.ItemsSource = 

        }

      

        private async void AllEvents_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AllEventsWindow win2 = new AllEventsWindow();
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            win2.WindowStartupLocation = 0;
            //win2.Left = 0;
            //win2.Top = 0;
            win2.Show();
            await AllEventsRetrieved.AllEventsRetrievedAndShowCount(win2.AllEventsDialogue);
        }
    }
```

I've tried to create a seperate class with the properties but I'm struggling to fully understand what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

`myVar` is declared inside the méthod so it will only be accessible inside this method.
If you want to access it from outside, you should make it a public property of the class `FailedIgnoredRetrieved` (note that in this case if you want to modify the property from the method `FailedIgnoredRetrievedAndShow` you will have to make it not static)

Another way would be to have the method return the list so you get it as result (the declaration would become `Task<List<string>>FailedIgnoredRetrievedAndShow(...` ).

There seems to be quite a bit of confusion in your code so I would recommend reading a tutorial about the scope of variable [you can start here](https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/variables/#aelm5686)
You should also check this answer about the access modifiers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/614844/13448212)

I would also recommend staying away from local functions (functions inside functions) at the beginning as I think it adds to the confusion.

Let me know if it makes more sense after reading the links in my answer

Comment: Ostas, thank you for taking the time, that's very helpful...Am I right in thinking functions and methods are the same thing? Now I just need to get my data binding right as currently it's printing one character per line!

Comment: Yes a method is a function that belong to a class basically. So for c# the correct term would be method but I often mix the two terms.