# MStest can't find neither the classes nor the namespace

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

This is the first time I'm trying to do unit tests so I'm pretty sure it's on me, but for some reason I'm not able to make them work.

I have a project, with some classes. The project is in 4.7.2 Framework .Net.

In the solution, I added a new project. I chose MStest for 4.7.2 framework .Net too.

[image]

Now, I added the references via Add references.

[image]

[image]

But even that, for some reason in the UnitTest.cs file, I can't call any classes. I can't even call the main one program.cs, it looks like it can't recognize the namespace. What's going on? What am I doing wrong?

Acording to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/getting-started-with-unit-testing?view=vs-2019&tabs=dotnet%2Cmstest)

```
 myNameSpace.Program.Main()
```

it should work, but it doesn't. There's not even showed the project's namespace

Comment: Anything being tested must have the `public` modifier so they are visible to the test project. `internal` can be tested if the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute) is added to the assembly being tested. Are you sure the classes you're testing are `public`?

Comment: They weren't public, now I can see the namespace so it seems to work. Just for curiosity; is it okay for classes to be public? Also, in this case the class wasn't preceded by the keyword public nor private, how is this type of class treated? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you're referencing the MSBuild NuGet packages that match the version of Visual Studio that you're using. Also ensure you have the Test Adapter packages referenced too.

Comment: "is it okay for classes to be public?" - yes. and no. Depends on your use case. As a new developer, make them `public` until you *know* why they should be anything else. By default, anything without a modifier (public, protected, internal, private) is `internal`. Here's some reading on SO to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614818 I'd recommend you spend some time learning the basics of C# development before you get much further.

Comment: @MetroSmurf Thanks, last thing I'll ask I promise, when people are testing, is it legit to change the attributes from only getters to also setters to change the values in the object property and test faster/easier? Of course leaving it afterwards as it was originally. What I'm asking is if people tend to do this and if is it kinda valid.

Comment: @Sharki - the target being tested (class, property, method, etc...) should never be modified simply to accommodate unit testing; doing so is a code-smell of either a poor design or a poor testing strategy. If a property is getter-only, then a new class should be instantiated with the expected value; never change the signature of a property simply to accommodate testing.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!